# How to implement these github examples?

Tags: javascript, html, css, github

All,

I am new to github and its a bit confusing to say the least. This link shows a bunch of animated menu styles, but I have no clue how to use their code on my sites. For example the 10th one down "Adrian". Where would I get all the code I need? I just signed up for an account. Thanks

http://tympanus.net/Development/LineMenuStyles/

Comment: You will probably just get downvoted with no answer unless you have a specific question involving code that people can see directly here in your post. No one is going to do the research for you.

Comment: Sorry @mariocatch I just meant that if there was anyone out there who has experience with seeing an example on the web where the free code is hosted in github and how to navigate the code files to find what you are looking for. I could use the guidance. This is the github link to the supposedly free code but I m not sure if what I am looking for is here. https://github.com/codrops/LineMenuStyles/ . I try and inspect the elements of the menu examples and reserch the css and JS but I'm not making the connection. why is this worth voting me down?

Comment: Note that the owner of the project is [Codrops](http://www.codrops.com/). Github just hosts the code. – As for the menus, the project doesn't appear to offer documentation for usage; only for [contributing additional styles](https://github.com/codrops/LineMenuStyles/#contribute). Though, you can use those instructions for find what you're after – the markup and styles for "Adrian" in the project's [`index.html`](https://github.com/codrops/LineMenuStyles/blob/master/index.html) and [`component.css`](https://github.com/codrops/LineMenuStyles/blob/master/css/component.css).

Comment: Thank you @JonathanLonowski that was the advice i was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the link you provided, click the GitHub cat logo. From there, you'll see that page's GitHub homepage. There is a button called "Download ZIP" - it's in the same line as the green "New pull request" button. Click that, and it will download all of the examples' code onto your computer.